# How do the visual studio notifications work

Tags: visual-studio

Anyone who has used recent editions of visual studio will be aware of the little flag in the window chrome that alerts or 'notifies' them of possible upgrades to certain components that they may have installed in visual studio, or indeed to visual studio itself.

I have managed to add a notification icon to my window chrome and I can control its appearance from the window's underlying view model.

My next goal is to try and get it to actually respond to external notifications. Perhaps somewhat predictably my first port of call was a search on Google but almost everything returned referred to Push Notifications.  I may well be wrong but somehow I don't get the impression that this is what is controlling the visual studio notifications.  I am aware (from having used Advanced Installer and it's auto update facility that it is possible to conduct a search at a specific web address, see if I particular text file there contains new information and then trigger responses based on that.

Would anyone know if that is the sort of thing the visual studio itself does.  I'm also intrigued as to how the notifications process keeps track of those items upon which you have acted, those upon which you haven't and whether or not you've actively dismissed all of them.  I would love to know the principle of how these have been implemented so that I can look at a way to emulate them in my own application and would welcome any information that can be proffered.

I intend to work in wpf and vb.net but can read c# hence the variety of tags I have appended to the question.

Comment: The easiest way is just to poll a webpage on startup or every X amount of time.

Comment: I doubt it uses push notifications,  it probably polls a Web API every so often.

Comment: As far as tracking what was installed or dismissed, each notification probably has a unique id,  studio probably keeps a file somewhere of the ones you dismiss or install.

Comment: @RonBeyer thank you for your suggestions, I'm not that familiar with the concept of polling web api's (in truth as of yet I know nothing about it) so I'll start by researching that and seeing what I need to do there.  The latter part in relation to unique id's for the actual notifications shouldn't be too difficult to implement.